# Quick way to create a pivot-table with totals from 2 dimensional data-points (part-id, year, units)?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I read out a set of data from a(n) SQL table using `pypyodbc`...
*(the SQL server call setup and details not included here)*
The result from the final `sqldata=cur.fetchall()` is this:

```
sqldata=[
('part00', '2023', 15), ('part01', '2023',  4), ('part02', '2023',  1), ('part00', '2022', 72), 
('part03', '2022', 48), ('part04', '2022', 22), ('part05', '2022', 16), ('part06', '2022', 16), 
('part07', '2022', 15), ('part08', '2022', 12), ('part09', '2022',  6), ('part10', '2022',  4), 
('part01', '2022',  4), ('part11', '2022',  3), ('part12', '2022',  3), ('part13', '2022',  2), 
('part14', '2022',  1), ('part15', '2022',  1), ('part02', '2022',  1), ('part16', '2022',  1), 
('part04', '2021', 35), ('part00', '2021', 20), ('part08', '2021', 18), ('part05', '2021',  3), 
('part07', '2021',  3), ('part09', '2021',  1), ('part16', '2021',  1), ('part03', '2021',  1), 
('part04', '2020', 43), ('part08', '2020', 15), ('part10', '2020',  9), ('part00', '2020',  9), 
('part07', '2020',  6), ('part05', '2020',  4), ('part17', '2020',  4), ('part03', '2020',  4), 
('part18', '2020',  3), ('part19', '2020',  2), ('part16', '2020',  2), ('part12', '2020',  2), 
('part20', '2020',  1), ('part09', '2020',  1), ('part21', '2020',  1), ('part00', '2019', 37), 
('part04', '2019', 18), ('part05', '2019',  8), ('part11', '2019',  5), ('part10', '2019',  4), 
('part22', '2019',  4), ('part16', '2019',  4), ('part23', '2019',  3), ('part03', '2019',  3), 
('part24', '2019',  3), ('part25', '2019',  2), ('part09', '2019',  2), ('part21', '2019',  2), 
('part20', '2019',  1), ('part13', '2019',  1), ('part14', '2019',  1), ('part19', '2019',  1), 
('part12', '2019',  1), ('part01', '2019',  1), ('part26', '2019',  1), ('part15', '2019',  1), 
('part04', '2018', 47), ('part00', '2018', 27), ('part13', '2018', 10), ('part12', '2018',  6), 
('part07', '2018',  4), ('part21', '2018',  3), ('part09', '2018',  2), ('part05', '2018',  2), 
('part15', '2018',  1), ('part04', '2017', 37), ('part00', '2017', 17), ('part12', '2017', 15), 
('part13', '2017',  7), ('part19', '2017',  6), ('part25', '2017',  2), ('part07', '2017',  2), 
('part03', '2017',  2), ('part27', '2017',  2), ('part21', '2017',  1), ('part09', '2017',  1), 
('part28', '2017',  1), ('part04', '2016', 49), ('part00', '2016', 29), ('part12', '2016', 12), 
('part02', '2016',  5), ('part15', '2016',  2), ('part24', '2016',  2), ('part08', '2016',  2), 
('part29', '2016',  1), ('part01', '2016',  1), ('part21', '2016',  1), ('part13', '2016',  1), 
('part28', '2016',  1), ('part25', '2016',  1), ('part04', '2015', 30), ('part00', '2015', 15), 
('part15', '2015',  8), ('part28', '2015',  5), ('part09', '2015',  4), ('part12', '2015',  2), 
('part02', '2015',  2), ('part01', '2015',  1), ('part13', '2015',  1), ('part29', '2015',  1), 
('part00', '2014',  6), ('part12', '2014',  2), ('part28', '2014',  1)
]
```

Based on this, I currently have my second attempt (a lot faster than the first) to create a table on the data.
This time by first creating "order" of the above - using a loop - inserting the data into a numpy array, then looping through the array to get:

```
          2023  2022  2021  2020  2019  2018  2017  2016  2015
Part00:      -    72    20     9    37    27    17    29    15  . 226
Part01:     15     4     -     -     1     -     -     1     1  . 22
Part02:      4     1     -     -     -     -     -     5     2  . 12
Part03:      1     -     1     4     3     -     2     -     -  . 11
Part04:      -    48    35    43    18    47    37    49    30  . 307
Part05:      -    22     3     4     8     2     -     -     -  . 39
Part06:      -    16     -     -     -     -     -     -     -  . 16
Part07:      -    16     3     6     -     4     2     -     -  . 31
Part08:      -    15    18    15     -     -     -     2     -  . 50
Part09:      -    12     1     1     2     2     1     -     4  . 23
Part10:      -     6     -     9     4     -     -     -     -  . 19
Part11:      -     4     -     -     5     -     -     -     -  . 9
...
Total: 908
```

There MUST be a simpler, shorter way to create this, isn't that so?

*Reading https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html, but cannot see the right tree because of the woods...*

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you want someone to answer whether or not your Python code is idiomatic. But there is no Python code in this question. There's some output and a table. What do you envision an answer to this question *critiquing*?

Comment: 1) and 2) added at the end... is that telling better what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, because you still have not shown us any of your Python code.

Comment: Right, not currently accessible though (this is part of daytime "skunk works"). Given the code status I'm not sure it would add to it though; as I say, a loop creating a numpy array, then looping through that array, in a basically unsortable way.

Comment: What is a "2D table" ? Every table is 2D - in data-science terms you seem to want a matrix from two dimensions (a) part-id and (b) year - with sums, right? Sometimes we call it also [pivot-table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

Comment: So, matrix it is. That is one of my problems, not using the expected wording ... Now Above you see a "Matrix", now stated in your words; the expected end result.

Comment: Please don't edit updates about the solution into the question. Questions are for questions, answers are for answers.

Comment: Q revised to be cleaner... The earlier included text was intended to clarify the actual goal (question), as that didn't seem to get through to readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With the help of

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html in @hc_dev 's answer,

among other things...*

This (revised) very short code snippet (in a *.py file)...

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.precision", 0) # no decimals please.

# create a Pands DataFrame from the source data
df=pd.DataFrame(sqldata, columns=['part', 'year', 'units'])
    
#create a pivot table with sums
pt=df.pivot_table(index='part',columns='year',values='units', fill_value='-',  
                  margins=True, margins_name='Sum', aggfunc='sum')

# Reverse the order of columns
pt=pt[pt.columns[::-1]]

# Display the result...
print(pt)
```

will print ...

```
year    Sum 2023 2022 2021 2020 2019 2018 2017 2016 2015 2014
part                                                         
part00  247   15   72    2    9   37   27   17   29   15    6
part01   11    4    4    -    -    1    -    -    1    1    -
part02    9    1    1    -    -    -    -    -    5    2    -
part03   58    -   48    1    4    3    -    2    -    -    -
part04  281    -   22   35   43   18   47   37   49    3    -
part05   33    -   16    3    4    8    2    -    -    -    -
part06   16    -   16    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
part07   30    -   15    3    6    -    4    2    -    -    -
part08   47    -   12   18   15    -    -    -    2    -    -
part09   17    -    6    1    1    2    2    1    -    4    -
part10   17    -    4    -    9    4    -    -    -    -    -
part11    8    -    3    -    -    5    -    -    -    -    -
part12   43    -    3    -    2    1    6   15   12    2    2
part13   22    -    2    -    -    1    1    7    1    1    -
part14    2    -    1    -    -    1    -    -    -    -    -
part15   13    -    1    -    -    1    1    -    2    8    -
part16    8    -    1    1    2    4    -    -    -    -    -
part17    4    -    -    -    4    -    -    -    -    -    -
part18    3    -    -    -    3    -    -    -    -    -    -
part19    9    -    -    -    2    1    -    6    -    -    -
part20    2    -    -    -    1    1    -    -    -    -    -
part21    8    -    -    -    1    2    3    1    1    -    -
part22    4    -    -    -    -    4    -    -    -    -    -
part23    3    -    -    -    -    3    -    -    -    -    -
part24    5    -    -    -    -    3    -    -    2    -    -
part25    5    -    -    -    -    2    -    2    1    -    -
part26    1    -    -    -    -    1    -    -    -    -    -
part27    2    -    -    -    -    -    -    2    -    -    -
part28    8    -    -    -    -    -    -    1    1    5    1
part29    2    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    1    1    -
Sum     918   20  227   82  106  103  102   93  107   69    9
```

... the almost perfect pivot-table.

Answer (score 2):

While consulting a Pandas tutorial might help here too, you might need some keywords and impulses to look into the right direction.

For a quick-start lets begin with a simplified example (just 4 data-points).
Using the Python-shell gives you quick feedback - a REPL.

#### Input

Define the data-set and print view the data-frame.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> tuples = [ ('part00', '2023', 15), ('part01', '2023', 4), ('part02', '2023', 1), ('part00', '2022', 72) ]
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(tuples)
>>> df
        0     1   2
0  part00  2023  15
1  part01  2023   4
2  part02  2023   1
3  part00  2022  72
>>>
```

#### Research on some terms, concepts and functions

In data-science and related Python frameworks numpy and panda, some terms are pivotal.

Here some of the keywords you might need for your desired 2D visualization, table, matrix or pivot-table:

- DataFrame, Series
- column, row, index
- sum, aggregation
- pivot table, matrix

Find them in the [User Guide — pandas 1.5.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html), could start with the introductory "10 minutes to pandas".

#### Pivot-Table

From Microsoft Excel or other spreadsheet calculation apps you might know the technique and "tool" of a [Pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

Try to find something similar in the Python world or pandas, e.g.:

- [Reshaping and pivot tables — pandas 1.5.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html)

Preview to refine:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=['part', 'year', 'units'])
>>> df
     part  year  units
0  part00  2023     15
1  part01  2023      4
2  part02  2023      1
3  part00  2022     72
>>> df.pivot_table(values='units', columns='year', aggfunc=np.sum)
year   2022  2023
units    72    20
```